# JavaScript function to loop in a loop iterator issue?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function func(){
 for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
   alert('g');
 }
}

for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
  func();
  alert('h');
}
```

What I expected was: gggghgggghgggghgggghggggh

but what received was just ggggh

I found out that's because there is function scope, not block scope in JS. What I'd like to know is how to preserve such a behavior. I mean to force something like block scope. Otherwise it's very easy to make really nasty bugs - e.g. while using a function somebody else wrote or the one you wrote yourself, but a few months earlier.

Comment: Not using `var i` is your biggest mistake.

Comment: `var` is not optional! Semicolons are not optional.

Comment: @epascarello - I don't want to start another "semicolons are mostly optional" argument (though they _are_ and you're wrong!), but I'm curious if there was a spot in the OP's code where you thought a semicolon was missing?

Comment: I love my mostly-semicolon-free JavaScript and Go code! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually doesn't have to do with function vs. block scope - it has to do with implicit global variables.

The short story: You are accidentally creating a *global* variable in your `for` loop - if you use `for(var i=0;` rather than `for(i=0;` you'll get the expected results.

The slightly longer version:

```
alert("typeof i: " + typeof i);
// Alerts "typeof i: undefined"    
function func() {
  // References the *global* variable `i`
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
    alert('g');
  }
}

// Creates a *global* variable `i` and sets it to 0
for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
   alert("i at start of iteration: " + i);
   // Alerts "i at start of iteration: 0"
   func();
   // `func` has just altered *global* state - here's the proof
   alert("i after call to func: " + i);
   // Alerts "i at start of iteration: 5"
   alert('h');
}
alert("typeof i: " + typeof i);
// Alerts "typeof i: number
// `i` is now in the global scope.

// Left as an exercise for the reader:
// try it again with `var i=0;` in both of the `for` loops.
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue with variable i's scope.

```
function func(){
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
   alert('g');
 }
}

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
  func();
  alert('h');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `i` as a local variable in your function:

```
function func(){
   var i;
   for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
     alert('g');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in other answers, your code doesn't work because you don't declare the `i` variable with [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), which automatically makes it global. So not really a function versus block scope issue. If you use `var` to declare your variable(s) then the scope of the variable(s) will be limited to the same function where the declaration is *including within any nested functions*, or global if not in a function.

If you use the same variable name in nested functions then the one in the inner scope is said to "shadow" the outer one; the inner function can't access the outer function's variable of that name in that case since using that name will only give it its own variable. So to speak. Though you can access global variables by treating them as properties of the `window` object.

> *"What I'd like to know is how to preserve such a behavior. I mean to force something like block scope. Otherwise it's very easy to make really nasty bugs..."*

Well no, once you start using `var` correctly it isn't difficult to avoid those bugs. But you *can* force block scope by introducing an immediately invoked anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    // variables created in this function are accessible
    // only within this function
    var x, y, z;
})();

console.log(typeof x); // "undefined" (x can't be seen from outside the function)
```

The parentheses around `function(){}` are required so that the function is interpreted as an expression and not a function statement; the extra `()` at the end is to cause that function expression to be executed immediately. A common use for this structure is to enclose an entire script in it so that no variables or functions in it become global and thus don't interact with other scripts loaded from other JS include files. (You can have pseudo-global variables within the block shared between several functions also declared within the block.)

So for example if you wanted to make the body of a `for` statement into a "block" with scope you could do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < something; i++) {
    (function() {
        var x = i;
        // do something with x
    })();
}
```